# How can vertices and lines be created just by repeatedly clicking of the mouse?

Tags: modeling

I saw a "clicking to created vertices" technique in a tutorial but have never seen this before. https://youtu.be/DFJorlee_VY

Anyone know how this is done? Also, how are is this polygon converted to a smooth line?

Comment: they aren't clicking in the tutorial.  They just have sped it up to look like they are clicking.  What is actually happening is they are extruding each vertex in edit mode around the shape of the shoe

Comment: CTRL-right-click will create a vertex joined to the previous one. I've not looked at that tutorial but assume that's what's being used then select the last and first vertex in the loop, hit 'M' merge at centre.

Comment: He is adding new vertices by moving his mouse cursor to the position he wants the new vertex to be then holding down the CTRL key and then using the Left mouse button. that is for Blender version 2.78, for v2.8x it is Ctrl key and Right mouse button. The join up first and last vertices could be shift selecting first vertex while last is still selected and hitting the F key. The "smooth curve" looks like a subdivision modifier set to  3 (or more) with the "on cage" option enabled in the top bar of that modifier.

Comment: yes, simple extrusions or ctrl shift right click, and for the Subdivision Surface you have the shortcut Ctrl + number (Ctrl 2 will give a subdivision of 2)

Comment: Just Ctrl - Right Click does it for me..